# Make the acronyms bold but not the symbols

Tags: symbols, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I would like to make the *acronyms* bold. I used `\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}` to achieve this. But there is a side effect: The text in the `\text{...}` of the *symbols* also got bold, which is not desired. How to get rid of this side effect?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[acronym,symbols,nomain,nopostdot,nogroupskip,nonumberlist,automake]{glossaries-extra}

\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{\medskip}   % Add vertical space after each glossary item
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
    \glossarystyle{long}%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
        {\begin{longtable}{p{3cm}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
        {\end{longtable}}%
}

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long}

\newacronym
[
    description=Evolutionary Strategy,
    longplural=evolutionary strategies
]
{es}{ES}{evolutionary strategy}
\glsxtrnewsymbol
    [description={Minimal element density}]
    {min-element-density}
    {\ensuremath{\rho_{e,\,\text{min}}}}
\makeglossaries


\begin{document}
\setglossarystyle{mystyle}
\printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Acronyms}]
\printglossary[type=symbols,title={List of Symbols}]
\glsaddallunused

\end{document}
```

Comment: And now you know why `\text` should **never** be used for things like this. That is not what `\text` is for. Use for example `\textrm` or `\mathrm`. (there are **so** many users who misuse `\text` this way because they don't realise that it does not do what they think it does).

Comment: @daleif Thanks for the tips! So is it a good practice to always replace `\textrm` or `\mathrm` with `\text` in math mode?

Comment: If you want text up right, `\textrm` (or `\textnormal`) or `\mathrm` (if your text is just ascii and your math font matches your text font). `\text` should never be used for for this for the reason you already saw.